# BibLatex Will Not Work With Options

Tags: beamer, biblatex, errors, biber

My code works perfectly with BibLatex when the argument is passed sans options, but an array of errors appear if the argument is passed **with** options. Below is the first bits of code which do and do not work (respectively):

`\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}` 
`\usepackage{biblatex}` 
`\addbibresource{sample.bib}`

and

`\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}` 
`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}` 
`\addbibresource{sample.bib}`

Does anybody have ideas about why that might be the case? Below I pasted a screenshot of the errors, hoping they help.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: I have tried changing the style, and seems like `style=apa` was causing the problem, others seem to work. Any ideas to solve that would nonetheless be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test in their system. Including sample bibtex data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get started with this code and see if it runs on your system.
It should do various compilations due to 'biber'. If it does not work, update your installation.

Then, after deleting ALL auxiliary files,  use your `sample.bib` to check if it is properly written. Review the .log file end to end to see `biber` warnings,  if any. (It must end with " Process exited normally").
Also if `biblatex` complains about the encoding.

If still fails please provide the complete code you are using, including the .bib file.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[%
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    natbib=true,
    sorting=ynt,
    language=english]
{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname37.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
author  = {George Greenwade},
title   = {The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
year    = {1993},
journal = {TUGBoat},
volume  = {14},
number  = {3},
pages   = {342--351},
}
@article{bertram,
author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces},
journaltitle = {JAMS},
date         = 1996,
volume       = 9,
number       = 2,
pages        = {529-571},
langid       = {english},
langidopts   = {variant=american},
shorttitle   = {Gromov invariants},
annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with a \texttt{volume} and a
\texttt{number} field},
}


@article{glashow19,
author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
title        = {{NASA} sends {MarsProve} to search for {L}a, {A}c, {T}h {P}a and {U} actinides to the {K}uiper belt},
journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
date         = 2019,
volume       = 22,
pages        = {579-588},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname37.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Guidelines} 
Start with    \citep{greenwade93}.

See also \citep{bertram} and  \citep{glashow19}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: slides]